# What's the best way to manipulate the way entries in a data base are displayed on my web page?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have a client I am building a small CMS for.  One of the functions is that he would like to be able to pick the order in which images display on a page.

In my mySql Database I have a table called image_info with the fields:

index (auto incremented)

img_url

img_link

I was thinking of adding an additional field called img_order which would be an int that I would refer to to sort the data returned to my php script.

I'm not sure if that is the best way.  I feel like I will have to be re numbering every entry in the database just to move one image up or down the list.

Is there a standard procedure for this type of function?

Thanks,
-J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that adding an `img_order` column is the easiest way, and it won't be hard be to renumber the fields.  For instance, if you're adding a picture at `img_order` position 15, just insert it with that value, then run the following query:

```
update image_info set img_order = img_order + 1 where img_order >= 15;
```

If you're removing an existing image, you'd have to decrease the `img_order` values for all images after that one:

```
update image_info set img_order = img_order - 1 where img_order >= 15;
```

And if you're moving an image from one position to another, you'd have to increment the `img_order` for all images between the original and new position:

```
update image_info set img_order = img_order + 1 where 
img_order between (least($old_img_order, $new_img_order), 
greatest($old_img_order, $new_img_order));
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to re-number on every position change. But the algorithm isnt too complex you can do it all in two queries.